# Can't "Browse" with phpMyAdmin, password error?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

This strange error pops up when I attempt to "browse" a table. I have my password, it's "root" So why doesn't it simply ask me to enter my password? This is utterly frustrating. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your password is wrong.

Comment: It never asked for a password

Comment: delete cookies, restart browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your config files. I had this same problem. There are a couple of different ways to log into your PHPMyAdmin. One is with a password and one is with a cookie and I think there is yet another option.

Check the documentation [here](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#cookie-authentication-options) and update your config file. Don't forget to clear your caches in case there is a problem also.

Comment: egghhh! It was the cache. What a headache. Thanks!

Comment: @prismspecs Aha! The cachemonster gets the best of us. You should accept my answer if you think it worthy.